# Can I specify a specific 'views' path for each router?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

According to [the Express Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set), I can use `<Application>.set("views", "my/views/path");` to set a generic directory to store my views in. I've set up my project so that each of my routes has its own directory with its own views (and other route-specific content) to compliment my sub-domain based approach. I would like to be able to do something like `<Router>.set("views", "router/views/");`, so that, when I want to render a page, I can simply call `res.render("homepage");` instead of `res.render("<router>/views/homepage");` for that specific router.

Right now, I have the following setup in my root `app.js`:

```js
app.set("views", join(__dirname, "domains"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// ...
for (const d in domains)
{
    if (d === "root")
        continue;

    const router = domains[d];
    app.use(vhost(`${d}.${process.env.DOMAIN_ROOT}`, router));
}
```

In my "blog" router (for my `blog.website.com` sub-domain), I have:

```js
router.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    res.render("blog/views/index", {
        title: "My Tech Blog"
    });
});
```

I would like to be able to specify a `"views"` directory for each router, something along the lines of `router.set("views")`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going with the sub-app pattern suggested by [this thread](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2524#issuecomment-104162922).

I changed the line at the top of my router file from:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
```

to

```js
const router = require("express")();
```

And instead of using Routers for my projects, I simply make use of sub-apps to specify independent view paths:

```js
router.set("view engine", "ejs");
router.set("views", join(__dirname, "domains"));
```